# How to show nagios alerts in alert dialogs in ubuntu?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I would like to show alerts from nagios popped up in alert dialogs on a remote ubuntu box. Is there a ready-made app/script that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a browser window on your nagios page, than keep this window running by `iconifying` them. When an alert is incoming, javascript send an `alert` which pop iconified window to show alert.